# Unable to extract tables from tabula or Camelot

Tags: python, dataframe, python-camelot, tabula-py

Tried to extract the below table using Tabula, but it was returning null dataframe. It was working fine for other kinds of similar tables.

[image]

Tried using Camelot as well but it didn't work as well. Any suggestions about how can I extract these?

Attached my code

```
from tabula import read_pdf 
from tabulate import tabulate
from tabula import read_pdf
import pandas as pd
# from tabula.io import read_pdf

Page_No = 1
tables = read_pdf('/content/page1.pdf',pages=Page_No,multiple_tables=True)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(tables[0])
df1
```

```
import camelot

tables2=camelot.read_pdf('page1.pdf', flavor='lattice', pages='1')
tables2
```

Comment: As you can read in Camelot docs (https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/how-it-works.html), you should try `flavor='stream'`, since your table has not demarcated lines between cells

Comment: It is working after adding the flavor='stream'. Thanks @StefanoFiorucci-anakin87

Comment: @StefanoFiorucci-anakin87, It was working sometime and next time it throws zero division error for the same table. Any clues?

Comment: It is a known issue: https://github.com/camelot-dev/camelot/issues/299
You can try to apply thw workaround suggested in the link...

Comment: But it was working before but after restarting the runtime, it stopped working for the same files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got fixed after adding  flavor='stream' and 'guess=False' in tabula.

```
from tabula import read_pdf 
from tabulate import tabulate
from tabula import read_pdf
import pandas as pd
# from tabula.io import read_pdf

Page_No = 1
tables = read_pdf('/content/page1.pdf',pages=Page_No,guess=False,stream=True)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(tables[0])
df1
```